# UIDevice.current.orientation inconsistencies when device is upside down

Tags: swift, uidevice, uideviceorientation

When I switch `UIDevice.current.orientation` and print `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` or `width` I get the correct values except for when the device is upsidedown. Here the `height` and `width` values are reversed. For example, in an iPhone 8 plus simulator, the `width` is 414 and the `height` is 736. But when the simulator is upsidedown, suddenly the `width` is 736 and the `height` is 414. The code looks like this:

```
switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight:
        print("landscape", " width: ", UIScreen.main.bounds.width, " height: ", UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    case .portrait:
        print("Portrait", " width: ", UIScreen.main.bounds.width, " height: ", UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        print("UPSIDEDOWN", " width: ", UIScreen.main.bounds.width, " height: ", UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    default:
        print("other")
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
landscape  width:  736.0  height:  414.0
UPSIDEDOWN  width:  736.0  height:  414.0
landscape  width:  736.0  height:  414.0
Portrait  width:  414.0  height:  736.0
```

The portrait and portraitUpsidedown should have the same `height` and `width`, but there is an inconsistancy. In portrait mode the short side should be the `width` so I guess there's something wrong with the upside down orientation. Or have I missunderstood how this works?

Comment: very strange, I checked on iPhone 8 and got the correct data: "UPSIDEDOWN  width:  375.0  height:  667.0", but on iPhone 8 Plus - same result as you

Comment: I guess that this may be a simulator issue (unfortunately, there is no real device of such a model at hand)

Comment: Ah, so this only an issue with the 8 plus simulator? Thanks for checking on other simulator devices. Never thought of that. :)